# Symbolic links between websites

Tags: website

Is it possible to create a symbolic link from one website's home to another website's home, so when I go to site1.com it shows content from site2.com?

I've tried a few things but they don't work. The directory structure is `/home/site1.com/public_html`, which I want to point to `/home/site2.com/public_html` if someone visits site1.com

Answer (score 2):

You must configure your web server to allow following symlinks; it is usually disabled by default for security reasons.

Comment: `Options +FollowSymlinks` in Apache.

Comment: symlinks are enabled, when i enter the symlink i get directed to the folder from ssh, but not when i goto the site itself.  I think i'm getting confused what folder i should be linking.

Comment: I've added the Options +FollowSymlinks to virtualhost.conf but I think I'm still getting confused with the symlink.  I want to point /home/site2.com/public_html to goto /home/site1.com/public_html, what should the syntax be.

Comment: Ok, its working kinda, now I've got a permissions problem